# NameError: name 'assigs' is not defined

Tags: python

I applied the kmeans method form scikit-learn on my dataset and afterwards tried to plot both the data and my clusters but keep getting thir error and don't know what more to do.

This is my code right now:

```
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

    def construct_dict(list_keys, list_values):
      res = {}
      for i in range(len(list_keys)):
      k=list_keys[i]
      for v in set(list_values):
          res[k]=res.get(k,{})
          res[k][v]=res[k].get(v,0)
          res[k][list_values[i]]+=1
      return res

    def print_result(matrix, assigs, y): 
      pred=list(set(y))
      res = construct_dict(assigs,y)
      print(res, "is a clustering obtained when K=", nclusts)
      silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(matrix, assigs)  #Compute the mean 
      Silhouette Coefficient of all samples
      print("For %d clusters the average sillouette score is: %f" % (nclusts, silhouette_avg))
      return res

    def bcubed(assigs, y, calcule='precision'):
      #calcule = precision ou recall
      summatory = 0.0
      n = len(y)
      if calcule=='precision':
         list_dicts = construct_dict(assigs,y).values()
      elif calcule=='recall':
         list_dicts = construct_dict(y,assigs).values()
      for dic in list_dicts:
         values_dict= dic.values()
         n_elem_dic=sum(values_dict)
      for value in values_dict:
        summatory +=(value-1)*value/n_elem_dic
      return summatory/n


  def k_means(nclusts, matrix, y):
     kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=nclusts, random_state=0).fit(matrix)
     assigs=list(kmeans.labels_)
     res=print_result(matrix, assigs, y)
     print('Precision BCubed:',bcubed(assigs,y))
     print('Recall BCubed:',bcubed(assigs,y,'recall'))
     return assigs

  for nclusts in [2,3,4,5,10,20,30]:
     k_means(nclusts, X_pca, y)
     print("--------------")
```

output:

> {0: {'ALL': 12, 'AML': 14}, 1: {'ALL': 35, 'AML': 11}} is a clustering
>   obtained when K= 2 For 2 clusters the average sillouette score is:
>   0.147925 Precision BCubed: 0.5602471200297287    Recall BCubed:   0.5528841607565012

...

```
    import pandas as pd
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    pd.DataFrame(X_pca).T.plot()
    plt.show()
```

Output: Got the plot just fine.

And now the part that gives me error:

```
    import pandas as pd
    k_means(5,X_pca,y)
    pd.DataFrame(assigs).T.plot()
    plt.show()
```

Output:

> NameError: name 'assigs' is not defined

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you declared variable named assigs? if u did, can you please show the declaration?

Comment: The idea is to provide a minimal (=as few lines of code as necessary) to describe your problem.

Comment: @boandriy I though that by declaring it in a fuction, when i called the function i would be able to use it. Just understood after that i had to declare it outside the function again. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not saving what kmeans is returning. Does this work?

```
import pandas as pd
assigs = k_means(5,X_pca,y)
pd.DataFrame(assigs).T.plot()
plt.show()
```